# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]',but it requires another model

Tags: sitecore-client, mvc, glass-mapper

I have created the ipagebase model.and its is used being in the mainlayout as

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc
@inherits GlassView<Project.MVC.Models.Shared.IPageBase>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="title" content="@Model.PageTitle" />
    <meta name="description" content=@Model.MetaDescription />
    <meta name="Keywords" content=@Model.MetaKeywords />
    <meta property="og:title" content=@Model.OpenGraphTitle />
    <meta property="og:description" content=@Model.OpenGraphDescription />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SampleLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The model is

```
public class IPageBase
{
    [SitecoreField("PageTitle")]
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("BrowserTitle")]
    public string BrowserTitle { get; set; }

    // public virtual bool ShowInNavigation { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("MetaTitle")]
    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("MetaKeywords")]
    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("MetaDescription")]
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("OpenGraphTitle")]
    public string OpenGraphTitle { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("OpenGraphDescription")]
    public string OpenGraphDescription { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("OpenGraphImage")]
    public Image OpenGraphImage { get; set; }
}
```

But when i am trying to see the preview it.following error is displayed.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]', but it requires model another model in project

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems the type of model you are using in your view is different and the model you are supplying is a different type of model. Please check the model you are supplying and define same model in your view.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information on how you are using this view. Are you using it from a Controller Rendering in Sitecore? In that case, please include the code of your controller.

Comment: please make sure u pass right model in sitecore your main layout rendering/Layout if its view rendering?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but if you are using GlassMapper you need to mark your mapped properties with the virtual keyword. And it is completely up to you, but normally you only prefix interfaces with "I". If it is just a regular class you would normally just call it PageBase.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am having this problem with a "Layout" this is not for controller or View rendering but "Layout"